# c++ structure containing object

Tags: c++, oop, struct

I want to create a struct let's say Mystruct,which contains an integer and a myObj object whose constructor takes 2 parameters(one of string and the other is int).I mean I want :

```
struct Mystruct{
   myObj obj();
   int a;
};
```

Now,after some operations, I want to create a Mystruct variable and initiliaze obj and a. To do that I write:

```
struct Mystruct* foo;
foo->a=5;
foo->obj=myObj("test",3);
```

Is it a good way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

caesar said that MyObj have two parameters as constructor. So, MyObj is similar to below code.

```
struct MyObj
{
        MyObj(string name, int number)
            : name_(name), number_(number) {}
        string  name_;
        int     number_;
};
```

And then, MyStruct have a MyObj as a member variable, so it has to have user-define constructor as like below, because MyObj has not default constructor, so MyStruct cannot have default constructor as well.

```
struct MyStruct{
    MyStruct(MyObj obj, int a)
       : my_obj_(obj), a_(a) {}
    MyObj my_obj_;
    int a_;
 };

 int main()
 {
     MyObj my_obj("tester", 1001);
     MyStruct my_struct(my_obj, 1);
     getchar();

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `Mystruct` does not *have* to have a user defined constructor. Whether to give it one is a design choice that depends on many things, but not the fact that `MyObj` may not be default constructable.

Comment: @juanchopanza I compiled this code on vs2010. Without user-define constructor, I got a compile error with ''MyStruct' : no appropriate default constructor available'. So, I wrote like above. If I still have mistake, tell me advice, plz. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Your struct doesn't contain an object, but rather, a function that returns one:

```
struct Mystruct{
   myObj obj();  // this is a function declaration
   int a;
};
```

It sounds like you meant

```
struct Mystruct{
   myObj obj;
   int a;
};
```

Then you can say

```
Mystruct foo; // default constructs obj: myObj must be default constructable
foo.a = 5;
foo.obj = myObj("test",3);
```

or

```
Mystruct foo = {myObj("test",3), 5};
```

Note the absence of pointers and dynamic allocation: you should only use those if you really need to, and if you know what you are doing.

For completeness, your attempt at pointers fails, because when you declare this pointer:

```
struct Mystruct* foo;
```

it doesn't point to anything useful (actually, it holds a memory address which you can consider to be random and points to somewhere you shouldn't be writing). So you cannot do this:

```
foo->a = 42; // Ooops, foo doesn't point to a MyStruct object yet.
```

You need to make `foo` point to a `MyStruct` object before using it in this way.

Comment: So, what is so controversial or wrong about this answer to merit a down-vote?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code snippet is invalid because you did not allocate memory for the structure instance.
Also you can not do that way. You should define a constructor in your structure that will call the constructor of obj  in the mem-initializer list  provided that obj has no default constructor.

Something as

```
struct Mystruct{

   Mystruct( syting s, int i ) : obj( s, i ) {}
   myObj obj;
   int a;
};
```

Comment: +1, but "you *should* define a constructor" is a bit strong: OP may need the type to be an aggregate. It is worth clarifying the implications of adding the constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza That the type would be an aggregate obj also must be an aggregate. However from the original post it is clear that obj is not an aggregate because it has a constructor with parameters.

Comment: No, aggregate-ness does not require the members to be aggregates too.

Comment: @ juanchopanza Oh, you are right! An object of the structire can be initialized as an aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `myObj` has no default constructor (without an arguments) you can't just create `Mystruct` with `myObj` uninitialized. The proper way is to pass `myObj` value (or, better, reference to value) through the `Mystruct` constructor:

```
struct Mystruct{
    myObj obj;
    int a;
    Mystruct(int a, const myObj& obj) : a(a), obj(obj) {}
};
```

Here `: a(a), obj(obj)` is so called *initialization list*. `a(foo)` means initialize `a` with `foo` on construction of `Mystruct` object. In the example above `a` member of Mystruct is being initialized with `a` value from the constructor arguments. Looks a little bit strange, but let to avoid cumbersome parameter names like `_a` and so on.

And then initialize it like this:

```
Mystruct foo(5, myObj("test", 3));
```

Comment: You can also use aggregate initialization. This doesn't require a constructor, so `Mystruct` can be left unchanged.

Comment: Thank you @juanchopanza, I missed it.